# smartparens face for enclosing parenthesis?

Tags: smartparens

`sp-show-pair-matching-face` is the current matching face.

I think smartparens also has a face to the enclosing open parenthesis.
I can't find its name

related question is, can I find out the face of text which I can't place my cursor to? (so I can use `C-u C-x =` to find the face)

Comment: `grep 'sp-.*-face' smartparens.el`?